# How can I generate a list of node features as Numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

For a Graph based machine learning task, I need to input a Numpy array in the following format. It's actually an array of array. I tried several options like vstack, concatenate, etc. but nothing works for me.

This is the format I'm having now.

```
array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

The ***shape*** of this input is:

```
(2, 3, 5)
```

But, I need to have a NumPy array with the ***shape*** of:

```
(2,)
```

That means the input should be ***an array of arrays*** as below.

```
array([array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32),
       array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert the current input (shape:  `(2, 3, 5)`) into the expected input (shape: `(2,)`)?

Thanks

Comment: Your current input `a` is a list of two arrays. It is not a NumPy object and does not have a shape (but you can convert it into a 2,3,5 array with `np.array(a)`). Please edit your question.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you. I edited my question based on your feedback. Initially, I'm having two panda Dataframes here. I'm using `np.array(df_features.values,  dtype=np.float32)` to convert those into a NumPy array and appending the arrays into a list using `l.append()`. I previously mentioned the output of that list. So, how can I convert this now to a NumPy array with the shape of (2,)?